# BrainTree JS Client V3 hostedField create doesnot invoke call back function

Tags: braintree

I am working on implementing BrianTree on IOS device using Cordova. The API work fine in android. However when running the same JS code on IOS. The callback function passed to braintree.hostedFields.create is not invoked nor the hosted fileds are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that config.xml allow-navigation did not have the permissions for iframes to connect to braintree server. Unfortunately braintree api does not make a callback indicating error in navigation.

For development purpose

```
  <allow-navigation href ="*"/>
```